# Why Rick teleports to desert regions in the movie?

Tags: plot-explanation, knight-of-cups

In *Knight of Cups*, Rick character suddenly teleports to desert region from city region.

If You see the movie, Rick(screenwriter) lives in city.

[image]

But sometimes he teleports to some desert like region, look like this:

[image]

Why Rick get teleported & again comes back to the city?

It happens **frequently** in the movie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is not teleporting; these are cross cuts, and indicate lapses in time.

This is the way Terrence Malick typically shoots his films, they are meant to be ruminant and sublime, not literal.

They are sometimes intended to provide an insight into Rick's consciousness (i.e moving to a desolate landscape like the desert when he is lonely), and sometimes it is simply a stylistic choice to demonstrate the passage of time.